renderAS="pdf" not converting to hebrew language
im using renderAS="pdf" in my vf page, when it converts to pdf file it does work fine for english text, but the pdf is not converting to hebrew language. Is there a way to do it ? using renderAS="pdf" ?
i want to text to strat from Right to Left

post some code? Did you put parameters like dir? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm?q=ltr ? You could make a page variable with this based on current user's language code

Sadly , VisualForce page as pdf do not support Hebrew and Arabic
you can vote this this Idea
